# Binding for PetaPoco with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, petapoco

I need to bind a PetaPoco database object with Ninject. In the documentation (https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Fluent-Configuration) the following example is given for SimpleInjector:

```
var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

container.RegisterSingleton<IDatabaseBuildConfiguration>(DatabaseConfiguration.Build()
    .UsingCommandTimeout(180)
    .WithAutoSelect()
    .WithNamedParams()
    .UsingConnectionStringName("myAppsConnection")
    .UsingDefaultMapper<ConventionMapper>(), Lifestyle.Transient);

container.Register<IDatabase>(() => container.GetInstance<IDatabaseBuildConfiguration>().Create())
```

My other bindings all look like the following.

```
Bind<IRepRepo>().To<RepRepoWeb>().InSingletonScope();
```

But I cannot find a clear way how to do this binding in Ninject.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. The key is to make use of ToMethod.

```
Bind<IDatabaseBuildConfiguration>().ToMethod(ctx =>
DatabaseConfiguration.Build().UsingCommandTimeout(180)
    .WithAutoSelect()
    .WithNamedParams()
    .UsingProvider<SqlServerDatabaseProvider>()
    .UsingConnectionString("xxxx")
).InSingletonScope();

Bind<IDatabase>().ToMethod(ctx =>
ctx.Kernel.Get<IDatabaseBuildConfiguration>()
.Create()
).InSingletonScope();
```